# nth-child not selecting all children as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am playing around with nth-child as a pseudo class in my CSS, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected. By doing nth-child(-n + 3) it should be adding the CSS to the first three elements of h4. For example,

```
h4:nth-child(-n + 3) {color: white}
```

- n = 0 --> 3
- n = 1 --> 2
- n = 2 --> 1
- Stops since we don't have a 0th child

However, I do not get this behavior when I have a H1 between the H4s. Here's my code.

```js
var text = document.createElement("h1");
text.innerHTML = "YOLOOO"
document.getElementById("homeBase").appendChild(text);

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  var el = document.createElement("h4");
  el.innerHTML = "Hey";
  document.getElementById("homeBase").appendChild(el);
}
```

```css
#homeBase {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

h4:nth-child(-n + 3) {
  color: white;
}

h4 {
  color: black;
}

#homeBase:hover {
  background: blue;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    background-color: pink;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}

body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="homeBase">
  <h4>Yo</h4>
</div>
```

Why is this happening? Or am I just missing something very simple? Only 2 H$s are white and not three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nth-child` cares about if the element is that numbered child of the parent. Use `nth-of-type` instead.

```js
var text = document.createElement("h1");
text.innerHTML = "YOLOOO"
document.getElementById("homeBase").appendChild(text);

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  var el = document.createElement("h4");
  el.innerHTML = "Hey";
  document.getElementById("homeBase").appendChild(el);
}
```

```css
#homeBase {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

h4:nth-of-type(-n + 3) {
  color: white;
}

h4 {
  color: black;
}

#homeBase:hover {
  background: blue;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    background-color: pink;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}

body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="homeBase">
  <h4>Yo</h4>
</div>
```